# Can't use upper jquery scripts via $.ajax with child

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

Best

I like to create a mobile web-app and I also like to use jquery's $.ajax for it.
But I think that "**jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js**" doesn't work properly. Because when I write the code that jquery.mobile has to modify it works [ *See < form name= ... @ index.php* ] but when I do the exact same thing in *home.php* which is called via the $.ajax, it doesn't work. Therefore I think that the *home.php*, can't reach the *.js* file from the index page.

**--------------  index.php  --------------**

```
<head>
<link href="./css/myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="./jQuery/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jQuery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jQuery/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- this scripts containts testInAddedScriptFuncties() -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/functies.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function test() {
    alert('ok');
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
  function load_page (source,page,par1,par2) {
        $.ajax({   
          beforeSend: function () {
                startVibrate(100);   
          },
          success: function () {

            $("#" + source).load("content/" + page, { "var": [par1,par2]})

          },
          complete: function() {

          }
        });
      }

  load_page("content","home.php");
});
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div> 

<form name="input" method="post">
   <input name="search-works" id="search-works" value="" placeholder="Zoek ..." type="search">
</form>

</body>
```

**--------------  Second page home.php  --------------**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       test(); <------ this works
       testInAddedScriptFuncties(); <----this works also 
       })
</script>

<!-- this doesn't work, it is visible but doesn't get modified by the js mobile-->
<form name="input" action="JavaScript:search()" method="post">
    <input name="search-doesnt" id="search-doesnt" value="" placeholder="Zoek ..." type="search">
</form>
```

I hope that you can help me and give me an efficient solution, because I think it can't be the intention that an user have to load the **jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js** script on every page.

Kind regards

**--------------  EDIT  --------------**

*@ the index page*
i've added a new script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/functies.js"></script>
```

- a function

  function test() {
     alert('ok');
  }

Comment: does your ajax has url and type etc.

Comment: I've changed "load_page_sup" into "load_page" (i've multiple functions of these & took the wrong one but now it is correct)
load_page("content","home.php") should start everything. The form is visible but isn't handled by the js script

Comment: in home.php, place js code inside _page div_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to write a trigger function which the mobile jquery needed.

```
function(){
        $("#id").trigger('create');
```

Thus the full solution:

```
$("#" + source).load("content/" + page,{ "var": [par1,par2]},function(){
        $("#" + source).trigger('create');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Load runs any js on the loaded page before returning it as a simple html string. If you want to use jquery mobile to modify the page output you either

1. Have to include jquery mobile on the loaded page and run it there, before it gets passed back by `load`.
2. Run any modifications to the form you get back from within your main page, after the content has been added to the DOM.

It might be worth thinking about what you are trying to achieve here, it's not clear from your question, but if we're talking about fetching a form element only `load` seems like overkill.

---

---

Original answer

Don't think this is anything to do with loading jquery on home.php. Your javascript is wrong.

1. You call $.ajax with no url, which means it will try and call the current page...
2. Within the success callback you then try and do another ajax request...
3. <del>But the ajax call never runs because it is defined as `load_page_pub` and you are calling `load_page`.</del>
4. If it did run you might hit problems because it expects four parameters and you have called it with two.

Ignoring those extra parameters for now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function load_page_pub (source,page) {

        //don't know what this does?
        startVibrate(100);

        $("#"+source).load(
            "content/"+page,
            {
                //can add options here but should check they are defined first!
            },
            function(text, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                //do something here if need be.
            }
        )
    }

    load_page_pub("content","home.php");
});
```

Comment: I've changed the "load_page_pub". it was a mistake on stackoverflow

Comment: doens't work either - but why do the other scripts and function succeed?

Comment: Ah so you are trying to use jquery to modify your form on home.php? Sorry I didn't get that from the question. Load runs any js on the loaded page before returning it as a simple html string. 

Please see my edited answer.